# Objective-C HTTP File Upload returning 0 Bytes

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, xcode, http

I am trying to run a HTTP request in order to save an image. A PHP script handels the POST, it seems to receive the name of the file which is manually set, but the file has no size nor is it saved.

The Obj-C code I'm using is:

```
    MyImage.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(MyImage.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/api/phptest.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];


    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"ipodfile.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);
```

And my PHP file looks like:

```
//echo basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploaddir = '/api/uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

echo $uploadfile."\n";
echo $file."\n";
echo $uploaddir."\n";
echo $_FILES["file"]["type"]."\n";
echo $_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024;
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Uploaded";
}
```

But the return I get in XCode is

```
2013-02-10 13:23:09.116 Dablia[3419:907] /api/uploads/ipodfile.jpg
ipodfile.jpg
/api/uploads/

0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the content-type, now your are using this :

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

try this instead :

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Also

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality);
```

from the doc :

> compressionQuality
>
> The quality of the resulting JPEG image, expressed as a value from 0.0
>   to 1.0. The value 0.0 represents the maximum compression (or lowest
>   quality) while the value 1.0 represents the least compression (or best
>   quality).

I also noted this :

```
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
```

Why are you doing this? you have already an NSData object (imageData)

Comment: Still nothing which is strange as PHP isn't even debugging the file type